# Google Maps 100% Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the code from here:

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html#basic_map

My only problem is that I can't find how to make the map 100% Height.

Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to set `height` for `html` and `body` tags also:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Look at [this example](http://www.sumbera.com/lab/GoogleV3/tiledWMSoverlayGoogleV3.htm).

Comment: It should also be noted that the `margin:0` and `padding:0` css rules must also be applied to the body tag (which is in your example).

Comment: Well, not necessarily, that depends on your taste. You need not to do it but you can.