# google maps 100% height not working at IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, google-maps

I want to add google maps into one of my webpages.
I am developing in asp.net and the map should be into form tag.
thus I had added the following code:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px;margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

This code works fine at both IE and FF. The map is displayed at both browsers.
Now, I want to make the map to fill the rest of the screen so I am changing the code to:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

This code works fine at FF but displays nothing to IE. Any ideas?

Comment: [Using a percentage height for the map div](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps 100% Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325677/google-maps-100-height)