# Google Maps 100% height not working

Tags: html, css, google-maps

Im trying to make a webpage with just a map and a Navbar from Bootstrap. I tried to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325677/google-maps-100-height) but i dont know what im doing wrong. When i change the CSS from the body it disappears.

My code is the following:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grupo 3 - Diseño Electrico!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!--link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" /-->
    <!--link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/responsive.less" type="text/css" /-->
    <!--script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js"></script-->
    <!--append ‘#!watch’ to the browser URL, then refresh the page. -->

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <style>
    #map {
        height: 700px;
        width: 1247px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
    }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
        restaurant: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
        },
        bar: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
        }
    };

    function load() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
            zoom: 20,
            mapTypeId: 'satellite'
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("loadposition.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Latitud")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Longitud")));
            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon

            });
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });


  }

  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

    </script>


</head>

<body onload="load()">



        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Another action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Another action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>



        <div id="map"></div>




</body>
</html>
```

How can i do it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: to make percentual height work the height of the parent node also must be set.

Comment: Sorry @Dr.Molle but what do you mean ?

Comment: `<div class="row clearfix">` needs to have a height set via CSS, otherwise the browser doesn't know how to calculate the height(100% of what?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickest solution is the one you referenced. The problem may be you not also targeting the map. Here is the simplest solution (sorry for messy map in the fiddle - side project I'm working on):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/rp4rduat/2/)

```
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I tried using the code but it also makes the map disappear.

Comment: Would you happen to have a live version of this somewhere? Google's dev tools could probably shed some light on this pretty quick. Might also help in seeing if there is some conflicting CSS.

Comment: @jhaws i deleted some divs in the code (modified the code) but still not working. You can see it live on: http://mojala.cl/diseno/index.html (here im setting the size of the map manually)

Comment: In the dev tools when I added the height: 100% to the body, html elements it displayed at 100% width and height, so I'm guessing there is some conflicting CSS or JS that doesn't like that. You can try adding an important tag -> height: 100% !important -- I normally don't like using those, but it might help to see if its simply a CSS issue on the body or html tags.